# Jersey ContainerRequestFilter gets empty entitystream

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

To validate the api key I have employed ContainerRequestFilter to read the JSON payload and parse the api key. I have following method.

```
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream();
    try {
        int read;
        final byte[] data = new byte[2048];
        while ((read = in.read(data)) != -1)
            out.write(data, 0, read);

        byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();

        request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));

        if (!validate(new String(data))) {
            throw new WebApplicationException(401);
        }

        return request;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(401);
    }
}
```

However, the data is getting always blank/empty. Without the filter the payload reaches the resource class and works just fine. Any clues as to why the payload is empty? I was testing this with Firefox's REST Client with JSON in the Body.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to call

```
validate(new String(requestEntity))
```

instead of

```
validate(new String(data))
```

because in the second case you can get an invalid JSON (if your payload is big enough).

Also you might want to consider using `MessageBodyReaders` to read your entity for you:

```
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    // Buffer
    InputStream in = request.getEntityInputStream();
    if (in.getClass() != ByteArrayInputStream.class) {
        // Buffer input
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, baos);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ContainerException(ex);
        }
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());
        request.setEntityInputStream(in);
    }

    // Read entity as a string.
    final String entity = request.getEntity(String.class);

    if (!validate(entity) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(401);
    }

    // Reset buffer
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = (ByteArrayInputStream)in;
    bais.reset();

    return request;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Applied the fix but still did not get the body. However, I have replaced my filter with LogginFilter and body is not printed either while headers are printed. Upon further inverstigation in LoggingFilter code `if(in.available() > 0)` is not passing the condition which suggests that entity stream is blank. I can see the payload with `sudo tcpdump -i lo0 -A port 8080`. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Exactly what I'm facing. `in.available` is giving -1.
 @user1516100: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that, somehow, the input stream is being read before your filter gets the `ContainerRequest`. Are there any other classes that still read in the data or is your *Jersey* setup somehow misconfigured so that the resource class is reading the input stream before your filter?